# ElasticSearch - Range query not working

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm new to ElasticSearch so sorry if it's noob question. I'm trying to get users who has salary less than some value but I'm getting this error:

```
query_parsing_exception: No query registered for [salary]
```

My other queries works fine, only `range query` is failing, this is my code:

```
$items = $this->client->search([
    'index' => 'offerprofiles',
    'type' => 'profile',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                "must" => [
                    "match" => [
                        "jobcategories.name" => [
                            "query" => $query['category']
                        ]
                    ],
                    "range" => [
                        "salary" => [
                            "lt" => 20
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "should" => [
                    "match" => [
                        "skills.name" => [
                            "query" => $query['skills']
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "minimum_should_match" => 1
            ]
        ],
        'size' => 50,
    ]
]);
```

If I remove range query then everything works fine, also I checked indexed values and salary is there (integer).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is not a valid DSL. In the particular you are missing a bunch of brackets in the `must` clause. The `must` in the bool query should be an array of clauses instead in the above it is an object with key `match` and `range`.

Example :

```
$items = $this->client->search([
    'index' => 'offerprofiles',
    'type' => 'profile',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                "must" => [
                 [
                    "match" => [
                        "jobcategories.name" => [
                            "query" => $query['category']
                        ]
                    ]
                 ],
                 [
                    "range" => [
                        "salary" => [
                            "lt" => 20
                        ]
                    ]
                 ]
                ],
                "should" => [
                    "match" => [
                        "skills.name" => [
                            "query" => $query['skills']
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "minimum_should_match" => 1
            ]
        ],
        'size' => 50,
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thank you a ton, now everything makes sense